# Can someone explain projects in Dev C++ and how to create and add files, etc to it

Tags: dev-c++, project-structure

I really don't understand the use of creating a project in coding. I have always done "new source file" when I'm writing some code. The tutorials I see always creates a new project when they start coding. I have a lot of question about projects like "can i add another source file to it besides the main.cpp", etc.

Comment: It's a way of organizing your code. Project normally represents a DLL or an exe. A solution may have a library and console applicaiton, two different projects inside of it.

Comment: new source file just make a text file and you have to compile it manually after. you can write your project in note pad and compile it by cmd. but in huge projects you should write about 5 line or more in cmd and usually you receive many errors. making projects do it all and IDE can help you to make project easier. you can do both compiling and linking but it is really hard to use GDB.exe(debugger). you should make project to use IDE benefits.